# Tomcat LDAPs Authentication with JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat, active-directory, ldap

I am new with JSP and Tomcat LDAPs. However, I need to connect both of them to generate an active directory login for my project. Anyone could possibly help me?

FYI, I found some tutorial about how to configure my Tomcat LDAPs. But, what I don't understand is how to connect it with JSP

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Tomcat to authenticate using active directory then I'd recommend using Tomcat's [built-in SPNEGO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html) support. Alternatively, you could just use the [JNDI Realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm).

You "connect" the JSP and the authentication system by defining some security constraints in web.xml. For more information see this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html) (it is for Java EE 5 but this aspect has not changed much since it was written).